# ¿Qué puedo hacer si no me imprime dentro de un for?

Tags: c

Quiero imprimir en un ciclo for, pero no imprime nada, fuera del ciclo sí me permite imprimir, mi problema es en lenguaje C

Comment: Pon parte de tu código (como el for donde intentas imprimir) para intentar ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de que lo estes haciendo bien, para imprimir un estado dentro de un ciclo for es necesario seguir la siguiente sintaxis

```
for(variable = 0; limite de la variable; sumar la variable)
printf("hello world"); // imprime las veces que limites

while(limite)
//aumentar las veces hasta llegar las limites
printf("hello world");
```